# What makes expeditions go faster?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

My explorer has been next to an artifact for a long time and was wondering what makes the expedition go faster? It's even worse that it's in miasma :< Thanks

Comment: Does the cities production rate have something to do with it?

Comment: Did you actually start the expedition? It should show you how long left, just like with a worker building a tile improvement.

Answer (score 1):

An expedition will always take 10 turns, and if expedition site is in miasma, the expedition unit will take 10 turns of miasma damage aka. 100 damage - if no miasma immunity has been achieved. If the expedition site is near a city or a outpost, you can always use workers or miasma repulser to clear it - requires ecology and leaf tech alien biology.